# Can I Return Following Statement As Static in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
  ------------------------------
  |  User Name   |   Falg       |
  -------------------------------
  |  Kapil       |  Attendance  |
  -------------------------------
  |  Kapil       |  Field       |
  --------------------------------
  |  Khan        |  Attendance  |
  -------------------------------
  |  Sri         |  Attendance  |
  -------------------------------
  |  Raja        |  Field       |
  -------------------------------
```

Desire Output :

```
  --------------------------------------------
  |  User Name   |   Activity1  |  Activity2  |
  ---------------------------------------------
  |  Kapil       |  Attendance  |  Field      |
  ---------------------------------------------
  |  Khan        |  Attendance  |  Field      |
  ---------------------------------------------
  |  Sri         |  Attendance  | Null        |
  ----------------------------------------------
```

I have tried this so far
the query for the same goes like this

```
   Select User_Code, DCR_Actual_Date, Flag "Activity1" From Tbl_Sfa_DCR_Master 
Where DCR_Status in(1,2) and Flag ='A' 
and DCR_Actual_Date Between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31')T1 
On (T1.User_Code =T0.User_Code and T1.DCR_Actual_Date=T0.[DCR_Date]) 
Left Outer Join (Select User_Code, DCR_Actual_Date, Flag "Activity2" 
From Tbl_Sfa_DCR_Master Where DCR_Status in(1,2) 
and Flag ='F' and DCR_Actual_Date Between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31')T2 
On (T2.User_Code =T0.User_Code and T2.DCR_Actual_Date=T0.[DCR_Date])
```

Can Any One Help Me Out. Can I Write a Query As Static ?

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: I Tried With If Condition But I Can't Get a Out Put

Comment: put it here that query also so we can work around

Comment: And also your expected output looks `off`. `Khan` doesn't have `Field` in sample data

Comment: Select 
User_Code,
DCR_Actual_Date,
Flag "Activity1"
From
Tbl_Sfa_DCR_Master Where DCR_Status in(1,2) and Flag ='A' and DCR_Actual_Date Between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31')T1 On (T1.User_Code =T0.User_Code and T1.DCR_Actual_Date=T0.[DCR_Date])
Left Outer Join
(Select 
User_Code,
DCR_Actual_Date,
Flag "Activity2"
From
Tbl_Sfa_DCR_Master Where DCR_Status in(1,2) and Flag ='F' and DCR_Actual_Date Between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31')T2 On (T2.User_Code =T0.User_Code and T2.DCR_Actual_Date=T0.[DCR_Date]) I Tried Myself & I Got a Output Too.Thanks Pohh. I Got a Output.

Comment: you can answer here as you got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
`Conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT [user name],
       Max(CASE
             WHEN Falg = 'Attendance' THEN Falg
           END) 'Activity1',
       Max(CASE
             WHEN Falg = 'Field' THEN 'Field'
           END) 'Activity2'
FROM   yourtable
GROUP  BY [User Name]
```

Or use `pivot`

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT CASE Falg
                WHEN 'Attendance' THEN 'Activity1'
                WHEN 'Field' THEN 'Activity2'
              END act,
              *
       FROM  yourtable) A
      PIVOT (Max(Falg)
            FOR act IN ([Activity1],
                        [Activity2]))piv
```

Comment: Can U Explain Me the First One?? Conditional Aggregate?